# Calling a script in ~/.profile stops my logging in

Tags: shell-script, gnome, login

I placed a call to a bash script in my `~/.profile`.

The script executes a CLI program to dim my screen at login. However, Gnome doesn't continue to log me in to my standard desktop after running the script.

Is there a way to make the `~/.profile` script call non-blocking? I'm happy to provide more details that might help you answer this. My distro is Linux Mint.

**Edit**

Contents of `.profile.`

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# Me
bash /home/eoin/repos/scripts/autostart.sh

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

And my script `/home/eoin/repos/scripts/autostart.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
bash ~/repos/scripts/redshift/redshift.sh
```

Which in turn calls another script :-P

```
#!/bin/bash
redshift -v
```

Comment: Please provide the script and the .profile.

Comment: Background your script. The shell is waiting for it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Background the script, i.e.

```
# Me
bash /home/eoin/repos/scripts/autostart.sh &
```